# Read data from MySQL database via javascript and change prop of radios accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, database

I have a single data stored inside a database. I've to read it via Javascript once the page is loaded and store it in a variable.

The data read from the database and stored on the variable will be also an ID used to understand which radio on my page check at the beginning

I'm using the code below were ID_VAR should be the variable read from the database, which is also the ID of a radio button

```
$("#ID").prop("checked", true);
```

I really can't understand how to read data from a database via javascript. Is it actually possible?

Comment: You probably don't want to be accessing a database directly from the browser.  Your page should make a request to a server which handles the database connection, and returns the data using a format that the browser can understand (ie. over HTTP or WebSockets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP + JQuery Ajax
    data.php

```
$dbh = new PDO(' --- connection string --- '); 
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable'); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$items = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($items);
```

Jquery code on html file

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.getJSON('data.php',function(data){
            var items = [];
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, item) {
                $("#"+item.id).prop("checked", true);
            }); 

        });
    });
</script>
```